# Is possible to work with a array attribute of my collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import Message from "./Message"
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie"
import InputMessage from "./InputMessage"
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { collection, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"
import { db } from "@/app/firebase"
import { useCollection, useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore"
import moment from "moment/moment"

const ChatRoom = ({ alert }) => {
    
    const messageRef = collection(db, "alert", alert.docId, "messages")
    const queryRef = query(messageRef, orderBy("createdAt", "asc"))
    const [messages] = useCollection(queryRef, {idField: 'groupId'})
    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(['isAuth', 'user'])
    console.log(messages.docs)

    const scrollTo = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollTo.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
    }, [messages])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 md:mb-[80px] mb-[100px] xl:mx-80 md:my-[20px] m-5">
                {messages && messages.docs.map(msg => <Message name={msg.data().author} key={msg.id} text={msg.data().text} photoURL={msg.data().photoURL} createdAt={msg.data().createdAt} uid={msg.data().uid} />)}
                <div ref={scrollTo}></div>
            </div>
            <InputMessage alert={alert} />
        </div>
    )
}
  
  export default ChatRoom;`

I'm trying to access the messages attribute that is in the alert, the code structure would be this

`const emitirAlerta = async (id, tipo, situacao, userLoggedIn, details = "", messages = []) => {
    try {
        await addDoc(collection(db, "alerts"), {
            tipo,
            situacao,
            id,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            uid: userLoggedIn.uid,
            author: userLoggedIn.nickname,
            details,
            messages
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

the messages attribute is an object list and I would like to access it to create a map on it and update it in real-time

I've tried many ways but don't work. Please help me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.